# Expertise needed - newbie looking for a NAS dual platform solution

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, nas, osx-leopard, imac

I need some help in setting up a NAS and to allow back ups from both OS X and Windows on the same device.

Will a Buffalo Quad NAS be the solution to my problem ?

The Kit:

Mac:
I have an old G5 mac that I need to back up and do a clean install on.  The Mac is running Leopard 10.58. This will be used primarily for producing music using Ableton, so once backed up and Leopard clean installed & Ableton is installed I'll need more than the 80gb drive installed to store the music files.

My wife has a MacBook Air and if we can back that up too that would be brilliant.

PC:

Dell 15 studio that is currently running vista but I need to back up this too before doing an upgrade to Win7.

Dead WD MyBook 500g

As my WD mybook that was used exclusively for my PC seems to have died, I'm looking for a storage & backup solution that will accommodate both systems.

Possibly later I may also extract the hard drive from the WD mybook later and seeing if I can retrieve the data from that if the drive isn't totally dead and it's the rubbish WD box that's the problem

The possible Solution:

I'm looking at a Buffalo Quad LS -QL /R5 NAS.
This has 2 TB made up of 4 x 00 GB drives - all wiped and clean.

The seller on eBay seems to have no idea if this will be suitable for what I need it for. But it is a bargain and I would love to take advantage of it if it would be workable for me.
The Questions:

Is there a relatively simple way of setting this up so that I can maybe split the array to use 2 drives for the Mac and 2 for windows ?

I don't really understand RAID, so if it doesn't need to use RAID so much the better.

I'll need to be able to back up the Mac using time machine and access individual  files and folders using finder. 
I'll use whatever backup software comes with Vista or Windows 7 for the PC and use file manager to move or access files and folders on the PC.

I'm not so bothered about using the Internet to access files as it will reside next to the Mac desktop and PC back ups can be done via USB or Ethernet as the Dell is portable although using it as a media centre via Apple TV or my smart Viera Panasonic would be a nice bonus via my wireless network.

As the Buffalo seems to have a web browser interface it seems do-able but I have no idea how to go about this, and what additional software may be required. 
I know Leopard offers bootcamp 
So I could run Windows on the Mac, but that doesn't seem a very elegant solution and I'm guessing won't get round the issue of file systems on the disks themselves.

With a limited budget but I need to find a solution for this without having to buy 2 new external drives and having to do all operations separately each time.

Answer (score 0):

You are overthinking this.

Provided all the devices speak the SMB (Windows Filesharing) protocol - which is extremely common and my googling of the device has - it will work fine with your Mac.  (Not to mention the specs specifically claim MAC support).

You can use the same space for Mac and Windows - no need to partition the drives.

As far as RAID goes, learn a little - its not hard conceptually.  All that RAID does is combine multiple disks into a single disk - either in such a way that it has a lot of space or is reliable.  Once you have done it once, you can forget about it.

That said, **you may have missed out on the greatest concern** - the age of the disks.  500 gig disks are likely to be very old - and the older a drive is the more likely it is to fail - Simplifying greatly, a hard drive has a 20% risk of failing each year, which means if its 5 years old the chances of it failing within a year are very high .   (If you use RAID1, you could get 1TB out of the system reliably, but when the drives start to fail you need to be ready to replace them - I would not be buying old spinning drives if I cared about my data)

Comment: Thank you - to be honest I need it work long enough to back up the mac, re install leopard and take any programs I need already installed that came with the Mac that I don't have the disks for. I can then run off the macs hard drive for a while backing up as I go as a safeguard. As the disks are easily swappable I can replace them later probably for tb's  - the disks on the buffalo has 1700 hrs or so .. iAs long as it will work initially with both in theory that's good enough. Thanks for your help I'll let you know how it goes :)